# What piece of software do you recommend to help me keep an inventory of only infrastructure equipment?

Tags: infrastructure, reporting, asset-management

I am aware of the popular suggestions for IT Inventory & Asset tracking software like Spiceworks, GLPI, Open-AudIT, etc.

Unfortunately, these pieces of software are not geared toward my specific requirements.  I'm in the unique position where I do not need to keep track of servers, workstations, printers and things of that nature.

All I need to keep track of is the Network Infrastructure, the load balancers, switches, routers, firewalls, IPS sensors, etc.

This means I do not need discovery capabilities or agents that need to be installed to monitor assets.

What I'm looking for very well may not be a IT solution at all honestly.  I would like a piece of software that will basically let me catalog our Network Infrastructure equipment, as well as associate attributes to that equipment like firmware version, software version, location, 3rd party software loaded, ports used, and so on and so on.  More than likely the piece of software would need to allow me to create my own fields.

It will also need to be able to run on Windows, preferably open-source but it doesn't have to be, and be able to run reports against the data as well as sort and group the information.

Also being able to import xml and/or csv data would be a big plus.

Is anyone aware of any piece of software that may be useful for my needs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shopping and product recommendation questions are off topic. Please see the FAQ.

Comment: Not really shopping.  I need a solution.  Similar to the other IT Inventory Tracking questions, just with unique requirements in my case.

Comment: @Fujin take a look at device42. There is support for custom key/value pairs for your  exact requirements and it runs on Hyper V as well.

Comment: Look again at Open-AudIT. Specifically, version 2 known as OAv2. It will do everything you have asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Excel. (Not being flippant but I think it meets most if not all of your needs).

**EDIT**

Microsoft Access would do the job as well.

Comment: Thanks @joeqwerty.  I was hoping for a more eloquent solution but that really may be what I am end up having to do.

Comment: I thought as much but at the end of the day Excel and Access are no slouches and if they get the job done...

Answer (score 0):

Any database or spreadsheet will do.  I use a MySQL database and "asset stickers."  Some of the places I've been at with a better handle on inventory management (and barcode scanners) have given me ones with barcodes, even almost got RFID tags once, but, the backend is always a database.

Excel's the common choice in business because it's ubiquitous and cheap, but any table will do.  Populate it with the things you're tracking in the rows, and the attributes you care about in the columns, and that's an inventory management system.  Once you have that, you can work on automation/delegation, but data in a table structure/format is really all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

Observium might be almost what you are looking for, it is more geared towards monitoring the network equipment, but may be able to solve your necessities.